# image dimensions newsletter mobile

Tags: image, mobile, media-queries, newsletter

*Question*: What would be the ideal image dimensions pertaining to newsletters delivered to mobile devices?

**Background**: I need to provide dimension specs to my graphics designer so we can deliver specific images related to the mobile device (using media queries).

**Target devices are**: iphone 3.5" , 4", iPad 10.1", iPad Mini, Android devices - Galaxy Nexus, Note, HTC One 4.7"

Thank you for your time answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your layout. Are the images going to be full screen width? Padding? A general rule in design is to make it big because you can always downsize without losing quality. If there is even the tiniest possibility you would need these images for something bigger, create them big or in vector graphics.

There is also the issue of retina display. If you want to cater to this you need to double your image resolution, however this makes the email slower to download. There is no correct answer, so it depends on your target audience as you'd be benifiting retina displays but putting out the rest of mobile users.